# print the elements of a list with brackets

Tags: list, printing, format

I want to print the elements of a list in which each element is bound by a bracket set `[element]`.

I was wondering how to make it look like this:

> a = [1, 2, 5, 6]

to print:

> [1] [2] [5] [6]

Thanks!

Comment: what language are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 0):

JAVA

```
   for(int i:list)
    {
       System.out.print("["+i+"]");
    }
```

C#

```
   foreach(int i in list)
    {
        Console.Write("["+i+"]");
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7

```
for x in a:
    print [x],
```

In python3

```
for x in a:
    print([x], end='')
```